# One database for one customer or one for all

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, database, architecture

In our project we have about 100 customers and so far we have a database per customer.
We are facing some issues about software updates and debugging, and updates are really time consuming as you can imagine.

One of my colleagues told me that it would be easier to have only one clustered database for whole set of customers.

What do you guys think about it ?

How could we use that architecture to have one customer in beta-test with some schema modifications ?

We think that we could have some kind of database replication but how can we merge with different schema without data loss?

Edit :

Let's say I have one database server ( SQL-01 ) and I have 100 customers on that database.
How can I do to take one customer to SQL-02 after some schema change, and after a period of beta-testing I want every one to be updated on SQL-01 with the new schema and my beta-test customer to go in the SQL-01 until the next beta-test.

Comment: You question is incredibly broad and almost impossible to answer without knowing details about your database, application, its purpose, usage scenario and so on and so forth.

Comment: [At what point does one database per client become unfeasible?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61212/at-what-point-does-one-database-per-client-become-unfeasible) • [What problems will I get creating a database per customer?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/what-problems-will-i-get-creating-a-database-per-customer)

Answer (score 2):

Whilst upgrades may be more painful, there are a number of requirements to be considered before you place all the customers in a single larger DB:

Security: Whilst you have the data in a single database you have no isolation protection for the data, e.g. it is co-located. You risk exposing one client's data to another very trivially with any single bug in the code. Using multiple databases, you get more isolation protection.

Upgrading: If all the clients access the same database, then the upgrades will be an all or nothing approach - you will not be able to easily migrate some users to a new version whilst leaving the others as they were. This means you can not schedule downtime based on an individual clients time-zone, they all go down at once.

Backups: You can make each database currently backup separately, if it is in one larger DB then every client's backups are mingled together. If a single client asks for a rollback to a given date you have to plan carefully in advance how that could be executed without affecting the other users of the system.

Beta Testing : As you have already noted, if you were wishing to upgrade an individual client for testing a new version, you would have to use a different database, or ensure every change made was backwards compatible so that no one else would notice. At some point there will be a breaking change and you then have a problem.

Scale : eventually, with enough clients and enough data, you run out of room scaling up, scaling out is cheaper, and easier if you have multiple databases, instead of one.

As per the links in the comments by Alex K. I would look to use automation to manage to overhead and minimize the problem of having a large number of DBs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you pointed out every downside I see using this kind of model. I'll wait for some answer from other person as well ! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best way from my point of view is to use one schema and one database for all customer => create a DatawareHouse and especially a  Star schema if you have lot of data...

For example : You can start by creating a table with id customer,name,region,city..Like this :

[image: An example]

If you want to have the 100 database you can use "ALTER SCHEMA" (with loop) :

```
ALTER SCHEMA TargetSchema TRANSFER SourceSchema.TableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would almost always have one database for all the customers.  SQL databases are designed for large amounts of data.  In fact, they are even more efficient on larger amounts of data than smaller amounts (because on smaller amounts, pages would tend to be partially filled).

The only reason to separate out different customers is when the project requires it:

- The requirement could be *explicit*, for some unfathomable reason.
- The requirement could state that data from two customers cannot be in the same database.
- There could be a requirement to customize the application for a particular customer.

In general, though, for performance, maintainability, support, and security, you only want one database.  Each table should have an appropriate customer id.

Comment: While I do not disagree that SQL Server can handle the volumes, I disagree that security is as much of a pro here, as it is a con - and it is a con. There are other operational reasons around DR and upgrade / downgrade timing which makes me disagree with the sentiment that you would 'almost always'